# Unity3D- Firebase Storage not working on IOS device - [2019.4.6f1]

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, game-development

My unity project uses firebase storage to store videos and call them on runtime. when i tried to upload it on AppStore, I got

> **ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no
> longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and
> reliability**

after searching on some forums I found out that it was an issue with unity Editor so I upgraded to an LTS release [2019.4.6f1]. the error[ITMS-90809] went away when I uploaded on testflight but now Firebase storage is not working on the device but it is working in the editor. tried to look at some logs and found out 2 suspicious lines.

> **cratedemob[1484:666186] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service**

> **cratedemob[1484:666186] Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.Networking: 113: Could not find specified service**

Screenshot:

[image]

PS: I am not an IOS developer, just know a little bit about deploying on AppStore.

Comment: I've asked about this a little bit, and you Firebase Storage _shouldn't_ use WebKit for anything. Can you share the code you're using that's causing the issue and confirm that you're using Firebase's SDK or one of the 3rd party ones (https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity)?

Comment: The FirebaseUI library includes a loader for Firebase Storage which implements SDWebImage, which from what I can tell tries to use WebKit for image downloading and caching.  I don't have a fix for this at this point, just highlighting the connection to Firebase.